# Why the second database not created when multiple datasources in Springboot application?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, datasource

I want to use two (Mysql) databases in my Springboot application. Following the instructions I use the following configuration

> app.properties

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = password

spring.seconddatasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db2?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true
spring.seconddatasource.username = root
spring.seconddatasource.password = password
```

> DataSourceConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {
    @Bean("dataSource")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .type(DriverManagerDataSource.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean("secondDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.seconddatasource")
    public DataSource secondDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .type(DriverManagerDataSource.class)
                .build();
       }
    }
```

The application starts without errors but only the first database (or whichever datasource bean is marked as primary) gets created. Why not the second?

EDIT:

Once I create the second database manually, the application connects to both of them just fine. It is the automatic creation of the non-primary database only that is causing the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using `@ConfigurationProperties` wrong. The annotation most certainly does **not** point a bean to the relevant configuration. The first DB gets created because, well, `spring.datasource.*` are actually standard Spring Boot properties.

If you wish to create two data sources, at the very least you'll need to set the appropriate properties (`url`, `password`) on the second one yourself. You may inject your custom properties (`spring.seconddatasource.*`) into the configuration class using `@Value`, of course.

Comment: The thing is, I am able to work with two databases once I create the second one manually. So the configuration works, it is just the automatic creation of the non-primary database that is causing the problems.